# Merge input-shaping, resonance-compensation and vibration-compensation tags as synonyms

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have the needed reputation on this site yet and I didn't seen another option to suggest this, so I'm suggesting it here.

Please make the following tags one, as synonyms:

- input-shaping (the Marlin term)
- resonance-compensation (the Klipper term)
- vibration-compensation (the BambuLab term)

They all describe the same concept to my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Seen that all three tags are all used on three questions (not separately) a single tag would have been more than enough. [input-shaping](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/input-shaping) would be sufficient.

If others would be using other tags, we could then decide to merge the tags for synonyms.

Comment: Those questions are all mine. I'm fine to use only the input-shaping tag, but as those three things are synonyms. To reduce potential duplicates and to increase seo, I recommend already setting them up as synonyms. As each sub-community might use their own term for the same concept, making it very confusing if the subject is unfamiliar to the user.